# Is there other syntax for this pointer operation?

Tags: c++, syntax

This is a really basic question, but I'm not sure how to google it.

I have a pointer to a vector (or array of pointers), say

```
vector<int *> *p;
```

Is there an alternative syntax for indexing this array, other than

```
(*p)[i];
```

akin to the -> operator?

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to a vector in the first place

Comment: You probably should not be using pointers for either of those types. Why are you not using `std::vector<int> p`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p->at(i)` is similar but does bounds checking and throws an exception if `i` is out of range. Looks nicer than both your and Luchian's solutions (IMO), and is a little safer.

Comment: I.e. is better in all respects~

Comment: @CatPlusPlus debatable. `at` is great if performance is not a down-to the wire thing, but if I'm developing a game where I need all the speed I can get, then checking for bounds every iteration probably isn't the best thing to be doing.

Comment: If you have pointers to vectors of pointers to ints you probably don't care about performance anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I will start using this, except maybe in some inner loops somewhere.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Please tell me again how games are CPU bound nowadays.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz obviously you haven't tried playing crysis 3 on max settings before... Unless you have one of the best machines in existence, I'd say that's pretty CPU/GPU bound.

Comment: OP is fun to take this alternate, I dont see any difference between `p->[i]` and `p->at(i)`. And I dont think OP is managing exception.

Comment: +1.  Note also that this chains well if the vector members are themselves pointers to objects (i.e. you can do *p->at(i)->foo(bar)* ).

Comment: @MarsonMao I do see a difference between `p->[i]` and `p->at(i)`, namely that the former is a syntax error.

Comment: Ah, truely is an error, sorry. Then mayne I'll declare a reference to `(*p)` and then use it as ordinary `vector`. By the way, is pointer to `vector` a bad idea? Because there's a comment with 5 up-vote below the question.

Comment: @MarsonMao - It'd be more usual to pass by reference, that's all - unless you're really planning to re-point the pointer.

Comment: @Useless: I see. But you make me think of another question, I will open a new one for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714670/should-my-function-retur-a-pointer-to-stdvector-or-a-reference-to-stdvector

Answer (score 6):

Yes -

```
p->operator[](i);
```

but it's not really better if you ask me.